# Load YAML without expanding tags?

Tags: ruby, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am loading YAML files (specifically CloudFormation templates) which may contain custom tags (e.g. `!Ref`) that I want to treat as ordinary strings, i.e. `YAML.safe_load('Foo: !Bar baz')` would result in `{"Foo"=>"!Bar baz"}` or something similar. This is because I want to traverse and manipulate the template before dumping it back out. I would prefer not to have to `add_tag` everything under https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html. I am currently using Psych and Ruby 2.0, but neither is a strict requirement.

Update 1: I meant to say that answers based on Ruby versions newer than 2.0 are fine.

Update 2: I added the CloudFormation tag to this case because registering a bunch of `!X` -> `Fn::X` conversions may turn out to be the least bad solution and I have no need for a general Ruby question at this point.

Comment: OK, let's suppose you got `{"Foo"=>"!Bar baz"}`. You do something with it, and then what? You want to convert it back into YAML? `{"Foo" => "!Bar baz"}.to_yaml` would result in `Foo: "!Bar baz"` -- which is not what you started with (it's a string now, tags aren't evaluated).

Comment: Why not just load it with `File.read`?

Comment: @JackTheRandom Affecting how YAML scalars are outputted seems realtively straight-forward, you override the relevant method in https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Emitter.html . It is still a good point though: doing something like https://github.com/burtcorp/regentanz/blob/ba75278a6b4ed70276ba506a1f3e83aa607b63d3/lib/regentanz/yaml-ext.rb#L13 may require maintenance, but is trivial to understand and maintain while re-constructing the output may be non-trivial, particularly if `baz` was instead a mapping or sequence. I would accept this as correct answer.

Comment: @Bittrance well, I can post it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's suppose you got `{"Foo"=>"!Bar baz"}` after parsing YAML.

You do something with it, and then you want to convert it back into YAML?

`{"Foo" => "!Bar baz"}.to_yaml` would result in `Foo: "!Bar baz"` -- which is not what you started with (it's a string now, tags aren't evaluated).

Going the way of parsing YAML is not trivial and perhaps something else should be done instead.

Comment: I ended up doing this: https://github.com/burtcorp/cuffsert/pull/37 . Let's hope CF does not add tons of new functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to have to create each and every type, what you
would need to do is make a generic tag handling routine, that looks at
the type of node the tag is on (mapping, sequence, scalar), then
creates such a node as a Ruby type on which the tag can be attached.

I don't know how to do that with `Psych` and `Ruby`, but you indicated
neither is a strict requirement, and most of the hard work
for this kind of round-tripping in `ruamel.yaml` for `Python`
(disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

If this is your input
file `input.yaml`:

```
Foo: !Bar baz
N1:
   - !mytaggedmaptype
     parm1: 3
     parm3: 4
   - !mytaggedseqtype
     - 8
     - 9
N2: &someanchor1
   a: "some stuff"
   b: 0.2e+1
   f: |
     within a literal scalar newlines
     are preserved
N3: &someanchor2
   c: 0x3
   b: 4    # this value is not taken, as the first entry found is taken 
   ['the', 'answer']: still unknown
   {version: 28}: tested!
N4:
   d: 5.000
   <<: [*someanchor1, *someanchor2]
```

Then this Python (3) program:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_in = Path('input.yaml')
yaml_out = Path('output.yaml')


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
# uncomment next line if your YAML is the outdated version 1.1 YAML but has no tag
# yaml.version = (1, 1) 
data = yaml.load(yaml_in)

# do your updating here
data['Foo'].value = 'hello world!'  # see the first of the notes
data['N1'][0]['parm3'] = 4444
data['N1'][0].insert(1, 'parm2', 222)
data['N1'][1][1] = 9999
data['N3'][('the', 'answer')] = 42

# and dump to file
yaml.dump(data, yaml_out)
```

creates `output.yaml`:

```
Foo: !Bar hello world!
N1:
- !mytaggedmaptype
  parm1: 3
  parm2: 222
  parm3: 4444
- !mytaggedseqtype
  - 8
  - 9999
N2: &someanchor1
  a: "some stuff"
  b: 0.2e+1
  f: |
    within a literal scalar newlines
    are preserved
N3: &someanchor2
  c: 0x3
  b: 4     # this value is not taken, as the first entry found is taken 
  ['the', 'answer']: 42
  {version: 28}: tested!
N4:
  d: 5.000
  <<: [*someanchor1, *someanchor2]
```

Please note:

- you can update tagged scalars while preserving the tag on the
  scalar, but since you replace such a scalar with its assignment
  (instead of updating a value as with lists (sequences/arrays) or
  dicts (mappings/hashes), you cannot just assign the new value or
  you'll lose the tagging information, you have to update the `.value` attribute.
- things like anchors, merges, comments, quotes are preserved, as are
  special forms of integers (hex, octal, etc) and floats.
- For YAML sequences that are mapping keys, you need to use a tuple
  (`('the', 'answer')`) instead of a sequence (`['the', 'answer']`),
  as Python doesn't allow mutable keys in mappings. And for YAM
  mappings that are mapping keys you would need to use the immutable
  `Mapping` from
  [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping).
  (I am not sure if Psych supports these kind of valid YAML keys)
- See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717146/1307905) if you need to update anchored/aliased scalars

Comment: Ah, my apologies! I meant Ruby *2.0* is not a strict requirement. The code needs to go into https://github.com/burtcorp/cuffsert so it needs to be Ruby. I really appreciate your effort, tho.